# Let X be a real random variable. If $E(e^ {λX})≤e^{cλ^2/4}$, then $P(|X| > δ) ≤ 2e^{−δ^2/c}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let c > 0 and X be a real random variable such that for any λ ∈ R. $$E(e^
{λX})≤e^{cλ^2/4}$$ Prove that, for any δ > 0, $$P(|X| > δ) ≤ 2e^{−δ^2/c}$$

The question stated that X is a real random variable. But $E(e^{λX})$ seems to be a exponential distribution for me. Does the nature of X affect how to solve this problem? I am kind of confused where to start. Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: O nooo... A *third* one? http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1479952/ http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1479330/

Comment: I did not know those questions exist before I posted this one. But thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

We can write $P(|X|\geq \delta) \leq P(X\geq \delta)+P(-X\geq \delta)$.
  By Markov's inequality, if $\lambda > 0$, we know that $$P(X \geq \delta) = P(e^{\lambda X} \geq e^{\lambda \delta}) \leq \frac{E(e^{\lambda X})}{e^{\lambda \delta}} \leq e^{\frac{c \lambda^{2}}{4}-\lambda \delta}$$ and $$P(-X \geq \delta) = P(e^{-t X} \geq e^{t \delta}) \leq \frac{E(e^{-t X})}{e^{t \delta}} \leq e^{\frac{c t^{2}}{4}-t \delta}$$Now, as $c >0$, $\delta > 0$, putting $\lambda = t =  2 \delta /c$ ,we get $$P(|X| \geq \delta) \leq P(X \geq \delta)+P(-X \geq \delta) \leq  e^{\frac{\delta^{2}}{c} - \frac{2 \delta^{2}}{c}} + e^{\frac{\delta^{2}}{c} - \frac{2 \delta^{2}}{c}} = 2e^{-\delta^{2}/c}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Markov's inequality was covered in class. But I will look into that!

Comment: You get a stronger bound because the first step, where you assert that $P(|X|\geqslant\delta)\leqslant e^{-\lambda\delta}E(e^{\lambda X})$, is false.

Comment: why is it false? @Did

Comment: @Kaustav use that $(|X| \ge \delta)$ is the union of events $(X \ge \delta)$ and $(-X \ge \delta)$ to write $P(|X| \ge \delta) \le P(X \ge \delta) + P(-X \ge \delta)$. Then apply your argument to both summands.

Comment: @Kaustav You first: where did you see it?

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks @kobe

Comment: @Kaustav just to add, you should probably add the steps $P(X \ge \delta) = P(e^{\lambda X} \ge e^{\lambda \delta})$ and $P(-X \ge \delta) = P(e^{-\lambda X} \ge e^{\lambda\delta})$ in your proof before you apply Markov.